# Seeking QGIS tool for auto correcting address ranges at new intersections

Tags: qgis, address, intersect

I do public safety GIS, which is primarily centerline work. A tool that I have found indispensable when creating intersections where I don't have exact address point data is the Intersect Line tool from ETGeoTools / Ian-Ko. See the picture below for details on exactly what it does. It's basically the planarize lines tool on steroids.

I have moved 99% of my workflows over to ArcGIS Pro, and am in the process of migrating many to QGIS as I recently made the switch to Mac hardware and am a huge fan of open source.

Is there a tool in QGIS that can do this same thing or something close?

[image: Intersect Polylines Tool Description]

Comment: ETGeoTools can be used in QGIS with python. see https://www.ian-ko.com/FAQ.html "All the functions of ET GeoWizards can be used in Python Scripts by calling ETGWRun.exe located in the installation folder of ET GeoWizards using the Subprocess Python module."

Comment: The intersect tool is a portion of ET GeoTools, not ETGeoWizards.  I wish!  Wizards is actually standalone without QGIS or Arc.

Comment: Please contact Ianko https://www.ian-ko.com/AboutETST.html he maybe able to accommodate your request.

Comment: I undeleted my dumb answer from yesterday after adding something that's actually useful.

Answer (score 1):

I dabbled at doing this in the graphical modeler over the last day and came up with a method that works pretty well. The only catch is that it only works if there are already vertices where two roads intersect and that the data supports M values.

I drew some dummy data (note that green are start vertices and red are end vertices):

[image]

And here is the attribute table with all that is needed:

[image]

Here's the model:

[image]

The steps are like this:

- **Extract vertices**: the resulting features include the M value of the vertex along the original line.
- **Field calculator**: create a string of the vertex coordinates in a new field with expression:

  - `$x || ',' ||  $y`
- **Field calculator**: count the number of vertex overlaps that have the same coordinates

  - `count("fid",group_by:="coordinates")`
- **Extract by expression**: extract only start, end, and intersection vertices:

  - `"distance" = 0 OR "distance" >= "length" OR "overlaps" >= 2`
- **Split with lines**: split the roads at intersections (using the roads layer both as input and splitting layer)
- **Join attributes by location**: do a one-to-many join of M and original road fid values into the split road segments
- **Extract by expression**: Remove redundant segments where the fid values don't match (to remove the joins from vertices belonging to another road)
- **Join attributes by location (summary)**: for identical road segments (one for each start and end vertex), summarize min M and max M values using *touches* predicate.
- **Delete duplicate geometries**: remove duplicate road segments
- **Field calculator**: calculate the address range bottom limit

  - `to_int(("Max_add" - "Min_add") * ("int_distance_min" / "Length")) + "Min_add"`
- **Field calculator**: calculate the top limit

  - `to_int(("Max_add" - "Min_add") * ("int_distance_max" / "Length")) + "Min_add"`

The result looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to look at the "Line Intersections" tool. It seems to be quite similar and is documented under [Vector overlay](https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectoroverlay.html?highlight=line%20intersections):

> Creates point features where the lines from both layers intersect.

Comment: Does this also have the capability of automatically re-calculating the address ranges?  That is the "killer feature" of this particular tool.  Using the tool to create the intersections automatically recalculates the address ranges for the resultant 2 new segments created on either side of the intersection.

Comment: I think you would need to do the math for that independently. It should be possible with some pre and post distance calculations.